# For loop to preg_replace

Tags: php

So i'm trying to do a for loop to check for the characters '{' and '}'

```
public function push(&$args){

    $patterns = array(
        '/{/' => '<?',
        '/}/' => '?>'
    );


    foreach($patterns as $match => $result){
        $string = preg_replace($match, $result, $args);
    }

    return $string;
}

$data = '{ }';
echo($test->push($data));
```

My problem is only one of the items will change, and thats the '}' can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're overwriting your `$string` on each loop with one in `$args`, so just change it to,

```
public function push(&$args){
    $string = $args;
    $patterns = array(
        '/{/' => '<?',
        '/}/' => '?>'
    );


    foreach($patterns as $match => $result){
        $string = preg_replace($match, $result, $string);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

*[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/Sbwkt2x5)*.